# link_to - make 2 object values become a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make a link with the following: '@grp.id -- @grp.captain.name'

I tried the code below:

```
<%= link_to @grp.id--@grp.captain.name, :controller => :groups, :action => :edit_grp, :id => @grp.id %>
```

But am getting the following error message:
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

My question is how do i make the 2 obj values a link?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= link_to "#{@grp.id}--#{@grp.captain.name}", edit_group_path(@grp) %>`

should do what you need in any recent version of rails.

Comment: I should add for anyone finding this in the future, `edit_group_path` assumes you've defined a `group` resource in your routes file.